# Cannot typing utf-8 in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Juno to write Android applications. I have a strange problem:

- If I types text (UTF8 characters) in other text editor (.e.g Notepad) and then copy/paste into Eclipse, the characters display correctly, but if typing directly in Eclipse, the characters seem to be converted to ANSI.

I have set text file encoding for project to UTF8 but nothing change.
Right click on file > Properties, the Eclipse shows the file encoding is in UTF8, but if i open file in Notepad++ and check Encoding menu, Notepad++ shows that file is in ANSI.

What is the problem here? please help!

Comment: What sort of computer are you on? Linux? Windows? Other?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly why you store all text in `strings.xml` files on android. They are encoded UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Encoding is not property of file, It is about how to treat this file. So changing ecnoding not actually changes anythings. It's Okay.
2. I think you edited "*.properties" file. In this case, You can't use "UTF-8" because It support only ISO-8859-1, since this file will be load in runtime dynamically.

Comment: I didn't edit anything, just create a new project, type some UTF-8 characters but they are converted to another charset, just copy/paste is work

Comment: What kind of file do you type in?